# Why soviet didn't bring back "laika" to earth & how re-entry logic works?

Tags: spacecraft

Was technology not developed that time to do reentry ?

When was the first attempt made to re-enter orbit ?

How did Soviet successfully did re-entry for Gagarin but not earlier missions ?

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is based on a false premise. Gagarin's Vostok 1 flight in 1961 wasn't the first successful reentry, the space dogs [Belka and Strelka returned successfully](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korabl-Sputnik_2) in 1960 already. In fact, Laika was the only space dog launched without an intention to return. Please take a look at the relevant Wikipedia pages and update your question accordingly.

Comment: What is "re-entry logic" and what do you mean by "re-enter orbit"?

Comment: "..based on false premise.."  ? I didn't understand this ?  I just want to know why USSR didn't bring back laika ? What was the technological limitations ? Kindly don't downvote valid question

Comment: @vikrami The technology did not exist. Its in the 2nd parapgraph about Laika on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Laikas survival was never part of the plan. The dog was launched atop Sputnik 2, which lacked re-entry capability as this had not (yet) been developed. Even if the USSR had wanted, they couldn't return the dog safely to earth at the time.

> Little was known about the impact of spaceflight on living creatures at the time of Laika's mission, and the technology to de-orbit had not yet been developed, so Laika's survival was never expected. Some scientists believed humans would be unable to survive the launch or the conditions of outer space, so engineers viewed flights by animals as a necessary precursor to human missions. The experiment aimed to prove that a living passenger could survive being launched into orbit and endure a micro-g environment, paving the way for human spaceflight and providing scientists with some of the first data on how living organisms react to spaceflight environments.

Despite Laikas demise, the flight proved that animals could survive the launch and the space environment, at least for a while.

Human spaceflight was developed in the USSR in the Vostok programme. But even the first Vostok spacecraft, called Vostok 1KP, was not designed for re-entry. It was successfully launched on May 15, 1960. The next six flights of the Vostok programme used the Vostok 1K capsule, designed for dogs and for re-entry. Belka & Strelka, the two dogs launched on [Korabl-Sputnik 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korabl-Sputnik_2) were the first animals ever to be returned to earth from space, on 20 August 1960. This was only the second object ever to be returned from space, after the US recovery of Discoverer 13. A major setback in this phase of the programme was the [Nedelin catastrophe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nedelin_catastrophe).

The first spacecraft designed by the USSR for human re-entry was Vostok 3KA. Before a human was put into these, there were two unmanned test flights to verify the capsule, [Korabl-Sputnik 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korabl-Sputnik_4) and [Korabl-Sputnik 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korabl-Sputnik_5). Those two flights both carried dogs that were successfully recovered.

This eventually lead to the Vostok 1 mission  carrying Gargarin into space and returning him safely.

In summary, Laika was launched on Sputnik 2, which was a very small and simple satellite without re-entry capability, because the technology to re-enter did not exist yet. Vostok 1KP still could not re-enter, but was a pre-cursor to Vostok 1K, which was able to bring back animals safely, which lead to the Vostok 3KA capsule able to bring back humans safely after two unmanned test flights. At the point where Laika was launched, the tech to bring her back safely simply did not exist and the dog was seen as expendable.

**Ressources**

- [Laika. In Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Laika)
- [Vostok programme. In Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Vostok_programme)
- [Vostok (spacecraft). In Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Vostok_(spacecraft))

Comment: Can you please share more resources on "..because the technology to re-enter did not exist yet..". I would like to know what all experiments were done on ground or in space about re-entry, why is it so difficult to do etc ?

Comment: @vikramvi There is a whole tag dedicated to re-entry on this stack: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reentry

Comment: Thanks for sharing

Answer (score -2):

Russians had the capability to bring dog alive back to earth.
They just never thought of it.
Thats according to scientists involved. They regretted that ill approach to dogs life years later when asked about it. Which shows how little they valued life at that time.

Comment: Hi Gustaw - please read existing answers before posting one, as well as our [about] and [answer] pages. You will see from the existing answer, that references Wikipedia, that Russians didn't have the capability at that time.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).